# Haskell function composition using foldl

Tags: haskell, fold, foldleft

I have defined the following function in haskell:

```
step :: [Int] -> [Char] -> [Int]
step stack str
    | str == "*" =  remaining ++ [x*y] 
    | str == "+" =  remaining ++ [x+y]
    | str == "-" =  remaining ++ [x-y]
    | str == "/" =  remaining ++ [x `div` y]
    | otherwise = stack ++ [read str :: Int] 
    where x = (last . init) stack
          y = (last stack)
          remaining = (init . init) stack
```

This functions takes and integer array `[10, 4, 3]` and a string operator `*` and applies the operator to the last two items in the array and returns the following array `[10, 7]`.

This is makes up part of an intermediary function, the end result is a reverse polish notation evaluator function.

**How can I utilise the `step` function I've defined and `foldl` to do the following**:

Take the examples string: `"10 4 3 + 2 * -"`.

Add each element onto the string until the first operator is encountered as so:

`10, 4, 3` Then apply the operator to the two elements onto top the stack and place the result on the stack:

`10, 7`.

Continue as so until the final answer is evaluated (`-4`)

**Answer:**

For the sake of completeness this was the function I arrived at with the help of @talex

```
rpn :: String -> Int
rpn input = head result
    where arr = words input
          result = foldl step [] arr
```

Comment: What is your queation?

Comment: @n.m. I've made the question clearer

Comment: Regardless of anything, you are using the list backwards. The natural way to implement a stack is to have the stack top at the head of the list, not at the end.

Comment: @n.m. it feels more natural to me to implement the stack using ascending indices as opposed to constantly appending to head

Comment: @n.m. would the way I've implemented it be incompatible with using foldl?

Comment: Fold takes a function that works with two things, and makes it into a function that works with a list of things. So if you want a function that works with a list of numbes, you start with a function that works with two numbers.

Comment: @n.m. this was my understanding too, but the task at hand insists I use the step function in the form i described above

Comment: Your feeling is distorted by your lack of experience.

Comment: You are trying to implement postfix notation, that way question becomes much simpler. Also your `step` function is essentially `foldr`

Comment: Sorry you can use a fold of course, you are not folding a list of numbers but an RPN list pf strings. Sorry about the confusion. The point about the stack still remains. You are doing it backwards.

Comment: Stack operations map 1:1 to primitive list operations. `empty = []; top = head; push = (:); pop = tail`. All of those are O(1). `last`, `init` and `(++)` are not primitive operations, all of them are O(N).

Comment: Reversing the list also lets you use pattern matching to define `x`, `y`, and `remaining` without the need for a `where` clause: `step (x:y:remaining) "*" = x*y : remaining`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foldl step [] ["10",  "4", "3", "+", "2", "*", "-"]
```

`[]` here is initial stack.

If you rewrite your step in the following way it will work faster:

```
step :: [Int] -> [Char] -> [Int]
step stack str
        | str == "*" =  (x*y):remaining 
        | str == "+" =  (x+y):remaining
        | str == "-" =  (x-y):remaining
        | str == "/" =  (x `div` y):remaining
        | otherwise = (read str :: Int):stack
        where x = head $ tail stack
              y = head stack
              remaining = tail $ tail stack
```

Comment: `last` is `O(n)` but `head` is `O(1)` same for `init`/`tail`

Comment: Also `init` required memory for new copy of the list, while `tail` is just return pointer to immutable structure.